# The program '[13492] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749

Tags: c#, .net-core

When trying to build and run a hello world dotnetcore console app the app closes without any exceptions. On the debug output I see the following.

> The program '[13492] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).

My project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "NuGet.CommandLine": "3.4.3"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

my program.cs

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("help me");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I am using the latest, VStudio update 3.

Comment: Any error that starts with 0x8 is due to an invalid pointer.  This could be due to an object not initialized or a reference to an object outside the memory limits of the program.  I suspect the program is compiling properly.  I would make sure I saved the application in a folder that you have read/write privileges. Then go into the project folder and delete the bin folder.  Then recompile and try again.

Comment: Do you have a `global.json` file?

Comment: Yes, I do have a global.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did have a global.json as @Lex Li and @DavidG proposed. The problem was some leftover bits from RC2. I uninstalled all core components, reinstalled, and rebooted. After that things worked again. Thanks everyone for your other solutions !

Answer (score 17):

This could happen if you don't have the correct framework installed. Go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-download to get the latest framework.

Comment: This was my issue. I had 2.1.402 but needed 2.1.403 (AKA 2.1.5). I was able to see the error once I ran it from the command line.

Comment: Thanks @BobF. I missed the version mismatch until I ran it through the command  line as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error. It turns out I had no files output in the target `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1` path.  Since there were no files, the process just quit. After investigating I realized that I forgot to re-enable (check) the `Build` option for that project in the Configuration Manager. Because the build didn't fail (was skipped) it compiled all the other assemblies and just ran. :) It was an older unloaded project I was just getting back to and forgot I had disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if the framework is not selected as well.

In my case the framework was not selected. Target Framework for the project was empty, not sure why. I am using VS 2017. I thought it would default to the lowest or the latest version of .net core installed.

When I selected the Target framework for the project, the breakpoint was getting hit and everything started working as expected.