# iis is immediately closed after publishing asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core

IIS Express is immediately closed after i try to debug my asp.net core project under it.
i am using visual studio 2015 update 3.

Thanks in advance

my packages are fine but for sake of completness here is project.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}, 
"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.1.0": {     
    }
},
 "buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},
 "runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
  }
},

 "publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
  ]
 },

"scripts": {
  "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath%    --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
 }
```

and this is my startup class:

```
  loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
  loggerFactory.AddDebug();
  app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Any messages in the Output window? Did you check the eventlog?

Comment: yeah, i checked them at first. there was absolutely nothing.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line "type": "platform" and start debug?

Comment: I noticed you have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools twice in the project.json, but with different versions. I think you can remove the first line and update the second line to the latest version.

Comment: Go to event log and see the error logged by IISExpress. It should give you some starting point. I wrote a post that contains some troubleshooting steps which you might find helpful:https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could reproduce this behaviour and I am pretty sure this is caused by missing .NET Core 1.1 runtime libraries. When you go to C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App you probably won't see the '1.1.0' directory.

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core and **install the SDK library** (select Current and SDK).

N.B. If you did try (as I suggested in one of my comments) to remove the "type": "platform" line (and adding the runtimes part (depending on your windows version) then you'll see it won't crash. Without having to install the runtime / SDK.

Comment: thanks, the solution you have posted did not solve problem. how i have update .net core sdk from page you have linked and that solved the problem

Comment: I needed to remove the old RC2 parts and I removed Everything in Programs and Features starting with "Microsot .NET Core 1.*". Then I installed the SDK library, run times and tooling,  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175242/the-program-13492-dotnet-exe-has-exited-with-code-2147450749

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1827

Comment: My problem solved after I downloaded and installed https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current

Comment: This answer is still valid till now (.Net Core 2.1.4)