# ASP.NET Core hard crash after upgrade to Microsoft.NETCore.App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 application which has been around for a while. It has been upgraded to .NET Core 2.2 a while ago however i noticed that it was still using

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
```

I am trying to upgrade all of the dlls including this one and move to

```
Microsoft.NETCore.App 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
```

When I try to run this localhost on my machine.  The application does compile but it crashes hard.  There is nothing in the log it does not hit program.cs `main()` or startup.cs.   It just dies.

I can see this in the windows event log

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Development\identityserver\src\IdentityServer\' failed to start process with commandline 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\web tools\projectsystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile "C:\Users\ll\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp88E7.tmp"' with multiple retries. The last try of listening port is '36399'. See previous warnings for details.

with an event id of 1020

if i Google that event id I get [DHCP scope full, event ID 1020](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/581e86b0-a163-46dc-b408-7936cb938484/dhcp-scope-full-event-id-1020?forum=winserveripamdhcpdns)

I have no idea how this could have anything to do with a DHCP server running on my local machine.

Which lead me to this [Transport configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#transport-configuration)  So i added  `UseLibuv()`  which did not help its still crashing with the same error.

What have I missed?

Comment: I think this has something to do with IIS Express rather than .netcore. I'd delete the bin/obj folders, restart PC and can't remember where but find the temp config for IIS Express and flush that. make sure that you DO NOT have a `Version` specified for the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package.

Comment: duplicate of [iis is immediately closed after publishing asp.net core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701879/iis-is-immediately-closed-after-publishing-asp-net-core-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the sdk for .net core 2.2.5

> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

added it and it all worked